# How to only rollback failed entries on psycopg2.execute_values or execute_many?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Basically I except `psycopg2.IntegrityError`s when when doing a batch insert via `psycopg2.execute_values`. If the exception is triggered - due to a duplicate primary key in my case - I `rollback()` the connection.

However, I still would like the rows that did not trigger an exception to be inserted. My current plan for handling this is just to (on exception) go through all values again in a for loop and individual insert statements, so all are inserted besides the row that excepted.

This is terribly inefficient afaik. Not only do I have re-insert all the acceptable rows, but I have to do it in a horrible inefficient way.

Q's:

1: Is there a way to handle this exception better in `psycopg2.execute_values` so I can still commit all the accepted values, and rollback the failed row?

2: If not, is there a more efficient option for doing batch insert where some rows may fail, besides iterating over the data-structure and individually inserting each row?

To give some context as to what the code looks like:

```
qry = """
        INSERT INTO delivery_pref_history ('val1, val2)
        VALUES %s
    """

conn, cur = my_pg_connect_function()

try:
    execute_values(cur, qry, [(val1, val2) for val1, val2 in zip(df_column1, df_column2)])

except psycopg2.IntegrityError:
    conn.rollback()
    logging.warning('Found duplicate primary key, rolling back')

   # Attempt inserts individually
   # New code, for loop over dataframe to insert individually

else:
    conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using postgres 9.5 or newer, you can use the ON CONFLICT statement to skip those rows:

```
INSERT INTO delivery_pref_history (val1, val2)
VALUES %s
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
```